# Spring Data: any better way in getting the first object in an ordered list of objects?

Tags: spring-data

I need to get the most recently updated object. The following is how I do it with Spring Data:

```
final PageRequest pr = new PageRequest(
  0, 1, Direction.DESC, "updateTime"
);
List<MyObject> objects = myObjectRepository.findAll(pr);
if (objects.size() > 0) {
    return objects.get(0);
} else {
    return null;
}
```

Note that MyObject has a field called UpdateTime. A non-database-specific solution is preferred.

Thanks for any input.

**--UPDATE--**

I selected an answer, but not sure it is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can do it via @Query annotation. http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query

I suppose in your repository interface you need to define method like

```
@Query("SELECT o FROM MyObject o ORDER BY o.updateTime DESC LIMIT 0,1")
MyObject findMostRecentObject();
```

If your database doesn't support LIMIT statement you can replace it with some alternative that supports by your DB.

Comment: Stan, would you mind expanding your answer with how-to code sample? Could you please also expand on its benefits? Thanks for your input!!!

Comment: Updated answer with potential solution

Comment: Stan, thanks for the updated answer! I hope to have  a non-database-specific solution.

Comment: Non DB specific query may looks like "SELECT o FROM MyObject o WHERE o.updateTime = (SELECT max(obj.updateTime) FROM MyObject obj)". Think this is standard SQL.

Comment: Thanks for showing this new non database-specific way. Is this the way better than what I show in the question? In what sense? If there is no other better answer, I will select yours. Thanks!